# Convert C# DateTime.Ticks to Bigquery DateTime Format

Tags: c#, sql, .net, google-bigquery

I have a column in my Bigquery table that is filled by C# Ticks:

```
DateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

This is something like: 638148714773184690

I want to convert it to Bigquery DateTime.

Comment: I would recommend using the Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V1 library that I'm involved in producing - then you can just provide the `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`) value and the field value will be converted automatically. If you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried, I'm happy to help provide an answer.

Comment: I just want to show the DateTikcks column with date time format(yyyy/mm/dd/ hh:mm:ss )   ForExample 638148714773184690=> 2023/01/08 20:10:01

Comment: Is there any reason you've stored them *as* ticks rather than as a BigQuery Timestamp? That would be generally much easier to use and more portable.

Comment: (I suspect you want `TIMESTAMP_MICROS` having divided by 10 (the number of ticks per microsecond) - but it would be better to use the Timestamp type to start with.)

Comment: TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've done to provoke that error... (and basically everything that we might want to know - it should all be in the question, not just in comments)